# Return Connection Error Status on Failed Connection to PostgreSQL Database

Tags: php, postgresql

How could I write the following php but with postgresql functions instead of mysql?

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

If I failed to connect to the database, output error. Would I use the `pg_result_error` function?

I believe it looks like the below. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Will test soon to validate.

```
if (pg_result_error_field($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to PostgreSQL: " . pg_result_error_field();
}
```

Since the return value for this function is NULL if the field does not exist or FALSE on failure. There above code should work, and only echo a failed response when a value is returned from the `pg_result_error_field` function.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error-field.php

Comment: If all else fails _and only as a last resort if you cannot get someone else to do it for you of course_ you could always just [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Postgre function equivalent to `mysqli_connect_error`. But, If the pg_connect trigger any PHP error on failure then you can use `set_error_handler` to catch it !